# What is the best way to join two arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

```
["nome", "idade", "sexo"]
```

and

```
["Henrique", 23, "M"]
```

What is the best way to recive this output using javascript:

```
[{field: "nome", value: "Henrique"},
{field: "idade", value: 23},
{field: "sexo", value: "M"}]
```

Comment: Use `.map()` to loop over one of the arrays and return an object that combines the elements of both arrays.

Comment: Define "best". Do you really have different competing ideas in mind, or are you just hoping someone will show you how to do it?

Comment: Or use a `for` loop that pushes the object onto a result array.

Comment: @barmar [related meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388855/proposed-canonical-how-do-i-turn-datastructure-x-into-y-in-javascript-using-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var fields = ["nome", "idade", "sexo"];
var values = ["Henrique", 23, "M"];

var result = fields.map((f, i) => (
  {field: f, value: values[i]}
));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var f = ["nome", "idade", "sexo"];
var v = ["Henrique", 23, "M"];

var result = [];

for(var x = 0; x < f.length; x++) {
  result.push({
    field: f[x],
    value: v[x]
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
arr1 = ["nome", "idade", "sexo"];
arr2 = ["Henrique", 23, "M"];
arr3 = [];

for(idx in arr1){
  let obj = {};
  obj.field = arr1[idx];
  obj.value = arr2[idx];
  arr3.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this

```
function(label, dataArray)
{
 var result = [];
 dataArray.map(function(d){
 for(var i=0;i<label.length;i++)
  result.push({filed:label[i], value:d[i]};
 }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the correct result.

Comment: now I see, what you are trying.

Comment: please try this
function(label, dataArray)
{
 var result = [];
 dataArray.map(function(d){
  for(var i=0;i<label.length;i++)
   result.push({filed:label[0], value:d[i]};
 }
return result;
}